# sscanf skip over white-space in beginning

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read in a string and parse it with sscanf. Although i don't want to read in any spaces in the beginning.

Sample string.

```
@a Bear Tiger

sscanf(strLine, "@%1s %64s %64s", dir, name1, name2);
```

I have that.

Problem is if the line goes in as say

```
        @a Bear Tiger
```

Should be:

```
@a Bear Tiger
```

that it will want to read in the spaces up to the @ character. How can i skip over white-space and read from the @ character.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for using correct field width specifiers in your `scanf` format string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sscanf(strLine, " @%1s %64s %64s", dir, name1, name2);
```

This is necessary because `scanf` only skips whitespace for (most) conversion specifications.  But `@` is an "ordinary character", not a conversion specification, so there is no skip.  However, adding whitespace to the format string forces input whitespace to be skipped.

Comment: +1, that should work. Was wondering why you deleted the answer.

Comment: @coda, I was second-guessing my answer for the reason stated in the two deleted answers.  `scanf` *does* skip whitespace in specifications.  However, I've figured out the distinction.